# We need to ask more questions!

Tags: discussion, questions

We started off great, with about 25 questions per day, but now we've slipped quite a bit, to **"needs some work"**:

[image]

I don't want to see the site closed after 90 days!

Remember, you can check how we're doing over at Area 51: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/42572/aviation

Comment: I'm trying to come up with at least one question every couple of days, even if I know the answer, and I've shared with friends (who are not yet involved!). It seems like the surge of active users has died down, is that a natural stage in area 51 proposals?

Comment: We're still above the 5 question per day "minimum", so we're not doing _too_ badly, especially compared to some of the other recent proposals. In fact the activity has come up a bit from the bottom, since a few days ago.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We're actually still doing alright considering the holidays. Everyone expected the site to dip during that time as it has. Next week is when we really need to return to a higher level of interaction and growth.

Everyone at SE has been very happy with the site so far, but you're right, we can't become stagnant in the long-term or the site is going to fail. We definitely need to take it upon ourselves to promote it. I don't think much more needs to be said than +1 for more users and more questions.

Comment: And of course the obvious corollary is that more users will bring more questions.